# Richfaces 4.3, rich:fileUpload, FileUploadEvent getData is null

Tags: richfaces

Hello fellow developers!

**Env:** JBoss 7.1, JSF 2.0, Java 6, Richfaces 4.3.3

**Problem:** *UploadedFile item* is initialised, *item.getName()* returns name of uploaded file but *item.getData()* returns **null**.

I want to read uploaded file but I'm unable to get to the content.

In variables view of the debugger I can see *item.uploadedResource.file* = C:\appservers\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\standalone\tmp\work\jboss.web\default-host\iCargo\richfaces_uploaded_file_8359107924056551868.tmp but there is no file at this location.

web.xml:

```
<context-param>
  <param-name>createTempFiles</param-name>
  <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Form:

```
<h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <rich:fileUpload id="upload" fileUploadListener="#{actionBean.uploadListener}" 
    acceptedTypes="xls,xlsx" immediateUpload="true" maxFilesQuantity="1">
  </rich:fileUpload>
</h:form>
```

Bean:

```
private UploadedFile item;
public void uploadListener(FileUploadEvent event) throws Exception {
   item = event.getUploadedFile();
}
```

Comment: Are you getting any exception on the server?

Comment: No. Console is clear but i've just dicovered that file is actually apearing at proper location for a second, and then disapears :) It is visible while I stop at breakpoint on "item = event.getUploadedFile();" line. Do I have to persist this file somehow to have access to it later in session?

Comment: change `createTempFiles` param value to `false` ...

Comment: Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\(..)\richfaces_uploaded_file_8820674655724591088.tmp (Unable to locate file) at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.6.0_29-ea] - when I try to get to item.getData() in other method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [Richfaces demo fileUpload documentation.](http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/fileUpload.jsf?c=fileUpload&tab=usage):

> createTempFiles boolean attribute which defines whether the uploaded files are stored in temporary files or available in listener just as byte[] data (false for this example).

So you need to change `createTempFiles` param value to `false` and it will be available to the listener as `byte[]`.

Hope this helps.

EDIT:

Just follow the example in the demo to get the data of the uploaded file.

Comment: createTempFiles=false and I get File delete failed: java.io.IOException: File delete failed just after FileInputStream fis = (FileInputStream) event.getUploadedFile().getInputStream(); in uploadListener method :( oh, and I did fallow example thoroughly.

Comment: OK. Few cleans&restarts, putting bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(event.getUploadedFile().getData()); into listener and miraculously all sprockets begin to work. Thanks for your time HashimR.

Comment: @HashimR..ho to create TempFiles boolean attribute in web.xml

Comment: @Karol..plz help to to solve same problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24822211/unable-to-upload-the-file-in-java